# Using javascript/regex to filter through dynamically generated <input> tags

Tags: javascript, regex, dynamic-content

I am currently trying to create a dynamic printable-document generator for my training department at work.  I would like the entire project to remain in Javascript/browser-side scripting, as I'm trying to gain knowledge in Javascript exclusively.  The UI is linked below (can't post images until I have 10 rep):

[Hosted on my personal website - cgiv.webs.com/Test Platform/Training Plan.png](http://cgiv.webs.com/Test%20Platform/2013_02_21_15_33_03_Training_Plan.png)

The issue I'm having is with regular expressions.  I am fairly new to Javascript, but VERY new to regular expressions within Jscript.  I'm currently using the following function to generate and identify three input texts per execution:

```
/*Variable Declarations*/

var i1 = 0;
var i2 = 0;

/* ------------------- */


function generateInput()
{

if (i1<15)
{
    i1++;
    var appendSpan = document.getElementById('appendSpan');

    var appendStr = "<div class='row'><input id='text_topic" + i2.toString() + i1.toString() + "' class='text_topic' type='text'/>|<input id='text_instructor" + i2.toString() +  i1.toString() + "' class='text_instructor' type='text'/>|<input id='text_date" + i2.toString() +  i1.toString() + "' class='text_date' type='text'/></div>";

    appendSpan.innerHTML += appendStr;
}
else
{
    alert("Action Cancelled.  Maximum fields reached.");
}

}
```

The i2 variable indicates the header number that the input fields fall under, where the i1 variable indicates the row that each cell falls into.  I would like to place a regex identifier script within the following function to pull the values from each cell and append them underneath their respective target spans within the "newPage" variable:

```
function createPage() 
{
var newPage = "<html><head><title></title>";
newPage += "<link rel='stylesheet' lang='text/css' href='output.css'>";
newPage += "</head><body>";
newPage += "<div class='head'>" + promptVal[0] + "</div><br/>";
newPage += "<span id='hcontent1'></div></span>";

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

/*  Uhhh.. Yeah.  This is where I'm lost */

newPage += "</span>";
newPage += "</body></html>";

var j = window.open('')
j.document.write(newPage);
j.document.close();
}
```

Once I can get, for example, text_(topic, instructor, date)(11-13) all within the "hcontent1" span, I can format it out.  I just want the data to be pulled from the text fields and placed into div tags on a separate page.

Thanks for your time, ahead of time!

Comment: Can you create a working example of what you have so far + what you have tried?  jsfiddle.net could help

Comment: jsfiddle.net is really cool.  Thanks for the tip.  I tried multiple methods for my regex match searches.  Pulled a for loop off of here that i couldn't ever get to work correctly, then I tried creating a new "Regex('blah')" object and running the exec() against the input[i] array iteration.  The problem with the latter, was that it was finding the character "1" I was looking for, but I couldn't figure out how to make it search a particular character number/index.

Comment: Why dont you use jQuery `$.each` and `$("input").val()` to loop on your inputs and capture the value of each.

Comment: Honestly I don't know the slightest thing about jQuery.  I'm trying to focus on basic javascript for the moment, then maybe move on to jQuery and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  After like three days of searching, this worked:

```
var regex1 = /1/g;

for (var i=0; inputs[i]; i++)
{
    if (inputs[i].id.search(regex1) == 10)
    {
        alert("It worked");
    }

    else if (inputs[i].id.search(regex1) == 15)
    {
        alert("It worked again");
    }

    else if (inputs[i].id.search(regex1) == 9)
    {
        alert("You did it, man");
    }

    else
    {
        alert("Skip this one");
    }
}
```